# TestNG + Eclipse - How to see the test list from a project before running the tests?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have multiple classes in a java project and each class is a test built with TestNG framework. How can I see the list of tests before running them?

Answer (score 0):

IMethodInterceptor shows the calculated tests, however it only has the ones which are not dependent.  More @ [site](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors) and [javadoc](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IMethodInterceptor.html)